# Consultas mysql con operaciones aritmeticas

Tags: mysql

He tratado de buscar algún tipo de consulta que haga operaciones aritméticas para mostrarlas en una tabla solo el resultado. He intentado con `count()` pero solo obtengo los datos y no las operaciones, como suma y multiplicación de las ventas.

Por ejemplo, de la venta 1 tengo 3 diferentes artículos obtener la sumatoria y si tuviera mas de 1 unidad también la multiplicación, algún tema que me recomienden leer para poder hacerlo? hasta ahora solo lo logro recorriendo el vector que me retorna la consulta y haciendo las operaciones con funciones php,

La consulta es normal:

```
SELECT * Fecha FROM `ventas`;
```

Lo que no se hacer es como hacer la sumatoria de todos los datos. Cuando aplico `count` y `sum` solo me retorna el valor de por ejemplo, venta 1 y no de todas las ventas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que solo me retorna numero de venta pero no la sumatoria de los artículos vendidos, es donde estoy atorado

```
SELECT NoVenta, COUNT(*) FROM ventas GROUP by NoVenta
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>No. Venta</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>550</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>700</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>800</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>900</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>500</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Lo que intentas hacer no se debería hacer desde tu archivo html y sus elementos, sino desde la consulta a la base de datos. haciendo un sum() de los precios de venta y agrupándolos según NoVenta. Para poder ayudarte mejor seria bueno que nos muestres tus códigos y consultas para darte una respuesta mas clara.

Comment: ya he agregado los consultas, soy muy nuevo en mysql y no logro integrar sum()

Comment: Es una simple consulta, no tiene nada de complicado. Ayudaría mucho que nos muestres tu consulta que usaste para conseguir esos resultados. Pero no lo subas como imagen, sino copia el código y dale formato.

Comment: disculpa si parezco algo tonto, pero cual código? el código de la tabla es el que genere como ejemplo de lo que espero conseguir desde mysql y no directamente de php porque bien lo dijo, no es algo que se deba hacer desde html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error esta en usar la función count(), esta solo cuenta los elementos. La que necesitas es la función sum() que suma.

```
select NoVenta, sum(PVenta) as total from ventas group by NoVenta
```

La suma está hecha con el campo PVenta, solo cambia el campo por el que necesites y listo.

Comment: en donde podría integrar la función sum()?  en NoVenta tengo los artículos que pertenecen id_producto, lo agrupe de esa manera, ahora como recorro o como hago la sumatoria de solo los productos que pertenezcan a NoVenta

Comment: La respuesta ya está editada con la consulta correspondiente

Comment: muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba, pero no sabía cómo hacerlo, gracias